# Measuring genetic distance: $F_{ST}$ vs. Nei's distance

Tags: genetics, human-genetics, population-genetics

As far as I'm aware, Nei's genetic distance is quite old compared to $F_{ST}$. However, I have recently read more papers that utilized Nei's genetic distance alongside with $F_{ST}$. As I'm not very familiar with Nei, what are some advantages it has over $F_{ST}$?

Does Nei's genetic distance suffer from ascertainment bias?

Comment: What do you call `Nei's genetic distance`? Do you refer to $D_{XY}$ or maybe to $G_{ST}$ or something else?

Comment: A note about formating: `$F_{ST}$` gives $F_{ST}$.  `$D_{XY}$` gives $D_{XY}$.

Comment: Nei was born about the same time as $F_{ST}$ was first defined by Wright. So, `Nei's genetic distance` (whatever this is referring to) cannot be older than $F_{ST}$.

Comment: Apologies, but Nei's genetic distance in this case refers to $D_{XY}$. Thanks. Nei's $D_{XY}$ might be newer than $F_{ST}$, however there have been more extensive uses and research on $F_{ST}$ to address its shortcoming. To this date, I'm wondering how Nei's $D_{XY}$ compare to the current $F_{ST}$.

Comment: The question's interesting but it will be very hard to offer a general answer. They are two different measures of genetic distance. $F_{ST}$ is better known, more studied and is more closely related with the population genetic theory than $D_{XY}$. Depending on the question of interest you might want to use one or the other. Many authors now recommend computing both to get a better picture of the genetic distances. Note that there are many other related statistics such as $\pi_S$, $\pi_B$, $G_{ST}$, $G_{ST}'$, $G_{ST}''$, $\theta$ (I mean Weir and Cockerham estimator of $F_{ST}$) and $Jost'D$.